# Elastic Beanstalk degraded status issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I was trying to upgrade a t1 micro instance to t2 from a shared image. But after the upgrade was successful my elastic beanstalk has been in degraded status with the following error -

```
Initialization failed at 2018-05-22T19:40:08Z with exit status 1 and error: undefined method `deploy_config_dir' for ElasticBeanstalk::Command:Class.
```

Comment: Is there a stacktrace associated with the failure in the logs?  Also, what is the "shared image" you have mentioned?

Comment: Shared AMI I meant. Its from my other account which has a t2 micro instance configuration.

Comment: Also where should I get the stacktrace from?

Comment: You should be able to get the logs through`eb logs` or through the AWS console by downloading the complete logs of your environment.